# How to place the origin of an isometric map at the top, not the left

Tags: c++, 2d, isometric, coordinates, allegro

I have an isometric diamond-shaped map. Currently my map origin is to the far left, instead of the top.

[image: Diagram of isometric coordinate system - green is desired origin]

The green circle at the top-center of the map is where I want the origin point to be, however the red circle on the far left is where it currently is now.

Basically when I walk "up" in my game, my x coordinates increase, where I would want them to decrease.

So far in my code I load in a text file with the following format

```
1 5 5 5 2
8 9 9 9 6
8 9 9 9 6
3 7 7 7 4
```

It's loaded with infile into a pointer of ints, from left to right, disregarding columns.

The edges and corners of the map above, are sides and corners of tiles - the middle (9) is a grass tile, that is walkable.

Here is how I get map segments of x and y (Terrain codes according to tileset):

```
int world_map::get_map_segment_x(int code) {
    if (code == 1) return 0;
    if (code == 2) return 64 * 3;
    if (code == 3) return 64 * 0;
    if (code == 4) return 64 * 3;
    if (code == 5) return 64 * 2;
    if (code == 6) return 64 * 1;
    if (code == 7) return 64 * 2;
    if (code == 8) return 64 * 2;
    if (code == 9) return 64 * 1;
    if (code == 10) return 64 * 3;
    if (code == 11) return 64 * 1;
    if (code == 12) return 64 * 2;
    if (code == 13) return 64 * 0;
    if (code == 14) return 64 * 3;
    if (code == 15) return 64 * 2;
    return 0;
}

int world_map::get_map_segment_y(int code) {
    if (code == 1) return 32 * 10;
    if (code == 2) return 32 * 7;
    if (code == 3) return 32 * 9;
    if (code == 4) return 32 * 9;
    if (code == 5) return 32 * 9;
    if (code == 6) return 32 * 8;
    if (code == 7) return 32 * 10;
    if (code == 8) return 32 * 7;
    if (code == 9) return 32 * 6;
    if (code == 10) return 32 * 6;
    if (code == 11) return 32 * 7;
    if (code == 12) return 32 * 6;
    if (code == 13) return 32 * 1;
    if (code == 14) return 32 * 10;
    if (code == 15) return 32 * 8;
    return 0;
}
```

Here is my world_map::render function

```
void world_map::render(int screen_width, int screen_height, float x, float y, int sprite_count) {
    int surroundings = 0;
    for (int row = surroundings; row < 20 + surroundings; row++) {
        for (int col = surroundings; col < 20 + surroundings; col++) {

            if (row >= 0 && row < 20 && col >= 0 && col < 20) {
                al_draw_bitmap_region(this->terrain, get_map_segment_x(map[2 * 20 * row + 2 * col]), get_map_segment_y(map[2 * 20 * row + 2 * col]), SPRITE_WIDTH, 32,
                     -32 / 2 + screen_width / 2 + (row - y) * 32 + (col - x) * 32, 64 - SPRITE_HEIGHT / 2 + screen_height / 2 + (row - y) * 16 - (col - x) * 16, get_map_segment_flag(map[40 * row + 2 * col]));
                    //-32 / 2 + width / 2 + (row - y) * 32 + (col - x) * 32, 64 - SPRITE_HEIGHT / 2 + height / 2 + (row - y) * 16 - (col - x) * 16, get_map_segment_flag(map[40 * row + 2 * col]));
            }
            else {
                al_draw_bitmap_region(this->terrain, get_map_segment_x(1), get_map_segment_y(1), SPRITE_WIDTH, SPRITE_HEIGHT,
                    -SPRITE_WIDTH / 2 + screen_width / 2 + (row-y) * 32 + (col-x) * 32, 64-SPRITE_HEIGHT / 2 + screen_height / 2 + (row-y) * 16 - (col-x) * 16, get_map_segment_flag(1));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

x & y parameters in render function are player x & y coordinates

If any more information is needed, please let me know, this has been bugging me for hours :(

Comment: I am still looking for someone to hopefully clear up why I have this problem :/